# Autofac: How to use construction injection on class with dependency to another object function output

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

This question is about IoC in general, but I'm using Autofac, so an Autofac solution would be great.

So assume the following classes:

```
class A
{
    IEnumerable<B> GetBs();
}

class B 
{
    // Some code
}

class C
{
    readonly IEnumerable<B> bs;

    C(IEnumerable<B> bs)
    {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.Register<A>();
        builder.Register<C>();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var c = container.Resolve<C>();
        // do something with c
    }
}
```

the above `Main` will fail.

I've noticed that I can solve this by adding this line of code:

```
builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<A>().GetBs())
```

However, that doesn't feel right. Any other way to achieve this? Or design changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As given, this class structure looks perfectly fine. You are properly using Constructor Injection and using the static structure of the classes to communicate **invariants and relationships**. On the level of information provided here, I think the only thing missing is a Guard Clause in the C constructor :)

On a conceptual level it's harder to answer whether or not this is a good design. That depends on context not provided here. Is B a **Service** or an **Entity**? What is the *intended* source of Bs?

As a general rule of thumb we should only inject Services, but handle Entities with Services (such as Repositories or Gateways or whatnot), so if B represents a Service it would be okay to inject it into C. If it represents an Entity, then it becomes suspect - unless C is also an Entity...

On another note you can ask about the **canonical source** of Bs. If A truly is meant to be the container of Bs, then the above solution is correct (and idiomatic Autofac code). If the Bs really have a different origin, resolving them through A may be a hack...

Comment: For simplicity reasons, I named the classes A, B, and C. But you are right in saying without context it's hard to determine if the design is conceptually correct.

Comment: Class A represents a plugin manager. The get function actually takes is actually generic and returns all plugin which implement a particular plugin.  Class B represents an implementation of a plugin.  Class C is a consumer which deals with only a particular type of plugin.  Thanks for the quick reply Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Given your reply to the accepted answer, there might be another technique to use in Autofac. If the set of plugins is available during registration, you could [register them as a collection](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Collections).

Comment: Good suggestion - you don't need to use the RegisterCollection APIs any more in version 2 though - IEnumerable<Whatever> can be resolved by default. I'll deprecate or drop the wiki page, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I thought that collections were resolved automatically in the current version, but I foolishly went with the documentation ;)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm using RegisterCollection<T>().As<IEnumerable<T>>() within the PluginManager. I can't use v2 because the plugin system is for a legacy program which is running on .Net 2.0